# Is icons a protected directory/keyword in Apache?

Tags: apache

I have a folder called icons under `var/www/html/dev` and I get the dreaded *You don't have permission to access this resource error* in the browser when I try to access the folder. The error goes away if I copy to a different folder (eg. `icons2` or `foo/bar/icons`). Also, this is not a permission error

```
/var/www/html/dev
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  css
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  extension
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  html
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  icons
│   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  download.png
│   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  magnifying-glass-1.png
│   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  next-1.png
│   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  prev-1.png
│   └── [-rwxr-xr-x]  url-address-bar.png
└── [-rw-r--r--]  index.html
```

Is `icons` a protected folder/keyword under apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

icons is an `Alias` defined in alias.conf:

```
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
```

On my Debian machine is located in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf`

Comment: So in a sense it is protected, but it is possible to disable the alias. by puttin a `#` in front of that line. Beware that in certain installations you might find this in `extra/http-autoindex.conf` I you don't have access to these—as you might have in a hosted environment—you cannot change this;. `.htaccess` has no effect on aliases.

Comment: I think we have to restart the `Apache` server after changing the file. In my case, I have to restart `Apache` server to make it work.